# Find a control's row number in an HTML table

Tags: c#, javascript

I have an HTML table called DataTable. In my C# code, I add several rows/cells to the table. The first cell of each row has a drop down list called "ddlLevels_[id]" where id is the corresponding id in the database.

My ultimate goal is based on certain options selected in the drop down list, to add a row under the current row.

How would I accomplish adding the row? I assume I need to find which row number this element is currently on and insert a row afterwards. How do I find that row number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every TR has a `rowIndex` property. Just traverse the DOM using `.parentNode` until you find the TR, then access its `rowIndex` property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534377(v=vs.85).aspx